# How to create a modeless dialog box and close it when the user clicks ok?

Tags: delphi

The user insists on a pop up box for each 'significant event" in the application. Adding a line to a memo or listbox is not aceptable.

I cannout use standard modal boxes bceuase the PC is often unnatended and my applciation will be left waiting for the user to click "OK" before it continues.

Can I just dynamically crate a form with a memo component and an OK button and pass some text to display in the memo?

I tried that and I got an access violation when OK was clicked.

Questions:

- is there any need to launch a thread to display the form, since it is being shown modelessly?
- what should I pass as the constructor parameter (prent)? Nil, since the form will destory itself?
- when the user clicks OK what should I call? Close() or Free() ?  Either of these gives an access violation approx 1/2 seconds after clicking OK, but if I do nothing in the function the code runs fine (with a memory leak, of course)

Google is not so helpful as the form should destroy itself, while examples have its creator destroying it.

---

In main form:

```
     theDialogForm := TDialogFormForm.Create(Nil);
     theDialogForm.ShowTheForm('Database error '+#13+#10+''+#13+#10+
                E.ClassName+#13+#10+
                E.Message);
```

and the dialog form ...

```
unit fDialogForm;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TDialogFormForm = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    OkButton: TButton;
    procedure OkButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
      procedure ShowTheForm(const theMessage : String);
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

// +=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=
procedure TDialogFormForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Visible := False;
end;

// +=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=
procedure TDialogFormForm.OkButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
//   Close();
   Free();
end;

// +=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=
procedure TDialogFormForm.ShowTheForm(const theMessage : String);
begin
   Memo1.Text := theMessage;
   Show();
end;

end.
```

---

call stack

```
main thread ($630):
005164e3 +013 StoreRoom.exe Vcl.Controls          TControl.WMLButtonUp
00515b30 +2d4 StoreRoom.exe Vcl.Controls          TControl.WndProc
0051a47b +5b3 StoreRoom.exe Vcl.Controls          TWinControl.WndProc
00537bf0 +06c StoreRoom.exe Vcl.StdCtrls          TButtonControl.WndProc
00519ad0 +02c StoreRoom.exe Vcl.Controls          TWinControl.MainWndProc
0048dea4 +014 StoreRoom.exe System.Classes        StdWndProc
76677885 +00a USER32.dll                          DispatchMessageW
005b7c63 +0f3 StoreRoom.exe Vcl.Forms             TApplication.ProcessMessage
005b7ca6 +00a StoreRoom.exe Vcl.Forms             TApplication.HandleMessage
005b7fd9 +0c9 StoreRoom.exe Vcl.Forms             TApplication.Run
00823616 +17a StoreRoom.exe StoreRoom      56 +24 initialization
75c43398 +010 kernel32.dll                        BaseThreadInitThunk
```

Comment: You can just instance a simple form similar to the messagebox, but that is modeless and display many.. you may run into issues if no one answers them all..  the access violation was a red herring it was something else in your code, form destroying itself - depends on the code..

Comment: If by chance you're using DevExpress controls you probably have the [Alert Window Manager](http://www.devexpress.com/Subscriptions/VCL/WhatsNewBuild11.2.2/index.xml?page=2) which seems to fit your needs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To close a form, you can either

- close it by calling `Close` and set action to `caFree` in the OnClose Event
- call `Release`, which is a special flavour of Free, especially for forms.

The problem with calling `Free`, is that the form is freed immediately, while you are still handling the click event on the close button. The form and therefore the button is freed while in that process, causing the access violation. `Release` internally sends a message to the form, causing it to close *after* the click is handled.

Comment: +1 and the answer. I just wish that I could give you more.  Thanks a 1,000,000

Answer (score 4):

1. You do not need a thread to display the form. But, since the form should remain visible, I'd suggest you set it's `FormStyle` to `fsStayOnTop`
2. Since you are destroying the form, you can pass `nil` to `Create()`
3. To destroy your form, call `Close` and in your form's `OnClose` event, set `Action` to `caFree`.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you make it easy on yourself and make an invisible panel that looks like a dialog box which becomes visible when a significant event occurs and invisible when the user clicks ok?

Comment: what if his app is using several forms ?

Comment: Then this solution is less desireable. The nice thing though is that this way you stay far away from threading.

Comment: you anyway stay away from threading - VCL is single-thread beast anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> is there any need to launch a thread to display the form, since it is being shown modelessly?

VCL is not multi-threaded. You should always run forms in the main thread.
You *maybe* may call Win32 API ShowMessageBox in extra thread, dunno, but only for a single message then. No way to accumulate events into TMemo or grid.

> what should I pass as the constructor parameter (prent)?

I'd pass Application, but it is not big deal.

> when the user clicks OK what should I call? Close() or Free() ?

Neither, there is no point to create/delete the form.
It only has sense when you can have many forms of the same class.
This time, just make Delphi auto-create and auto-dispose it when the program starts/ends.

You only should show it or hide it. No point in creating and disposing manually.

---

Now, about thread - why should you block your application at all?
Make that window AlwaysOnTop, then use [TApplication.OnActivate](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/forms/tapplication.onactivate.html) event to check when user switches to it and to bring that window to front and to the center of screen/mainform. So that user would see it.

*Or you may try 3rd-party notifications tools like Snarl with options for messages to never expire.*